# How to arrange and style child columns of dynamic height and width such that the parent element has the right dimensions, without using tables?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry, I know that title isn't very parseable (or even complete). This should do better than words:

[image: layout example]

Note that x and y are dynamic heights based on the contents of those children, and there is no guarantee that one will be larger than the other.

I don't want to use tables and I don't want to rely on CSS3 (for solutions like calc.) I *think* this means that one of the two columns must be taken out of the "static" layout, because of the dynamic width requirement. And because of that, I *think* that means there is no way, outside of Javascript, to size the parent container to the max of its children columns' heights.

I hope someone proves me wrong, because I'd love to do this in CSS. Thank you, wonderful SO community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fKxXb/1/)

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#wrapper, #main{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Quick follow up question: why exactly does overflow: hidden in #main have the behavior that it does?